# File Regex with extension c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check the name of the file. it supposed to accept only letters with an extension of .xlsm

I tried this:

> ^[a-zA-Z]+$.xlsm

can anybody please explain a little bit about this regex if it is correct. 
what the ^, +, $ means? and should I add something?

thank you

Comment: have you read any documentation on how to use `RegEx`?

Comment: Have you even read anything on how regex actually work? There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: `^` matches the start of the string; `$` matches the end of the string.  This will never match anything because you're trying to find ".xlsm" after the end of the string.  Go [read up on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: okay, thank you for the links. I think I understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small summary but read the full docs.

^ means beginning
$ means end
+ means 1 or more matches of that element
? matches 0 or 1 element
[a-zA-Z] means alphabets in both upper and lower case

```
string input;
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+\.xlsm";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.[put options]);
```

Comment: "afsbd.xlsmw23ew.xlsm" will break that. You need the ending $.

Comment: I agree though not a real time scenario in this case but it is better to be safe then sorry

Answer (score 1):

**^** indicates the start of the string, **$** indicates the end of the string. That means that the whole string has to match your regex, and not just a part of the string.

**[a-zA-Z]** matches every alphabetical character from a to z (lowercase and uppercase).

**+** is a quantifier: in your case it means 1-infinity occurences of **[a-zA-Z]** in a row.

What you want is this: **^.+.xlsm$**, look here for an explanation (this is a regex debugger): https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```js
var filename = "test.xlsm";
if ( /\.(xlsm)$/i.test(filename) ) {
alert("matched")
}
else
{
alert("not matched")
}
```

**edit**

better way to check extension in `c#` would be like:

```
var filepath = @"file.xlsm";
var extension = Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToUpper();

if (extension == ".XLSM") {
    // is an Excel file with xlsm extension
}
```

Comment: Or even, `if (filepath.EndsWith(".xlsm", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)){}`